# Не корректно работает терминал на Anarchy Linux

Tags: linux, sudo

Если работать из под обычного пользователя, всё работает корректно, кроме действий в терминале через sudo. Всё работает по стандарту, ввожу пароль, но в итоге: Felicia is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
А есть работать из под root, то всё ок, но, почему-то не работает хромиум.

Comment: добавьте себя в список sudouser. Где то так `usermod -aG sudo username`. Но что такое Anarchy Linux - я не знаю

Comment: добавлю, что группа, которой разрешено выполнение sudo может называться и по-другому, как то `sudoers`, `wheel`, `admin` или `sudo`, а может её и вообще не быть... за подробностями смотри содержимое `/etc/sudoers`.

Answer (score 1):

во-первых, не терминал, а программа *sudo*, во-вторых, работает она абсолютно корректно. ведь было совсем неправильно **по умолчанию** вновь создаваемому пользователю давать возможность совершать административные действия.

если верить «образцовому» [содержимому файла `/etc/sudoers`](https://github.com/deadhead420/anarchy-linux/blob/master/extra/gui/sudoers), то по умолчанию вызывать программу *sudo* может (вероятно, автоматически создаваемый во время установки) пользователь с именем `user`:

```
...
user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

с помощью программы *visudo* (рекомендуемый путь для редактирования файла `/etc/sudoers`), запущенной от имени пользователя с именем *root* (или «тем самым» — *user*), вы, к примеру, можете добавить имена нужных вам пользователей, через запятую:

```
...
user,пользователь ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы не в sudoers, но можете работать под рутом, значит, знаете его пароль. А ещё это значит, что у вас каноніческая юниксовая система подъёма привилегий, и надо использовать не `sudo`, а `su`.